# Ajax call to local .py script works fine until I add a simple import at the top, upon which it fails with a 500 error

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

This is all happening on the Django platform.
Here is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'get-dropdown-contents', //a url mapping to controller_ajax.py
        dataType:'json',
        data: {'selection_path': selectionPath},
        success: function (data) {
               //blah blah blah.... it doesn't reach here
```

Here is the .py script that is called:

```
from hs_restclient import HydroShare, HydroShareAuthBasic
from django.http import JsonResponse
from functions import irods_query


def get_dropdown_contents(request):
    print "Entered"
    if request.method == 'GET':
        selection_path = request.GET['selection_path']
        irods_data = irods_query(selection_path)
        return JsonResponse({
                                'success': "Response successfully returned!",
                                'irods_data': irods_data
                            })


def upload_to_hydroshare(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        hydro_username = request.GET['hydro_username']
        hydro_password = request.GET['hydro_password']
        try:
            print hydro_password
            print hydro_username
            hs = HydroShare(auth=HydroShareAuthBasic(username='joe', password='shmoe'))
        except Exception, err:
            print "Err: " + str(err)
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Username or password invalid'})
        return JsonResponse({'success': 'Response successfully returned!'})
```

The ajax call, which calls the get_dropdown_contents() function worked perfectly fine. However, with the simple addition of the `from hs_resclient import`... statement, the ajax call now fails with a 500 internal server error. If I comment out that one statement, the call works without a problem. I cannot figure out why for the life of me.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have the possibility turn on `DEBUG` in Django settings. Looks like your import simply fails for some reason, so you receive a `500`, because something went wrong and was not catched anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
```

to the top of the python file.  This should redirect the traceback to the browser when the Internal Server Error occurs and give you more information.  Remember to remove this for production.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem working on the web server because when I created new documents they did not have correct read/write/execute permissions. Could that be the issue with the document you are trying to include? And do you need to include the "py" file extension to the file name " in the ajax call?

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'get-dropdown-contents.py', //a url mapping to controller_ajax.py
        dataType:'json',
        data: {'selection_path': selectionPath},
        success: function (data) {
               //blah blah blah.... it doesn't reach here
```